# Python: print out all key values with the satisfied key condition

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list of dics:
keywords=[

{'WordType': 'Mod', 'Word': 'diagnostic'},

{'WordType': 'Key', 'Word': 'feature'},

{'WordType': 'Key', 'Word': 'substancemedication'}

]

How to iterate the list to get the value with only 'Key' WordType?

I've tried:

`next(item for item in keywords if item["WordType"] == "Mod")`

and

```
def search(Mod):
     for word in keywords:
         if word['WordType'] == Mod:
             return word

 search("Mod")
```

But none of them continue the iterating.
I want the result to be like:

key feature

key substancemedication

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a list comprehension to filter by key.

**Ex:**

```
keywords = [{'WordType': 'Mod', 'Word': 'diagnostic'}, {'WordType': 'Key', 'Word': 'feature'}, {'WordType': 'Key', 'Word': 'substancemedication'}]
def search(Mod):
    return [word for word in keywords if word['WordType'] == Mod]

for i in search("Key"):
    print("{}  {}".format(*i.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
Key  feature
Key  substancemedication
```